# php variable not matching mysql column

Tags: php, html

```
$division = array("5a7","8a10","11a12","13","14","15","16a17");

$number = $division[array_rand($division)];
```

This is my code for getting a random number from the array.  Which works fine.  However I then use the $number variable in a select command to mysql server and it says query failed: unknown column '11a12' in 'where clause'.  But 11a12 is a value in my column.  The strange thing is it works fine when the random value is 13 or 14.

```
 $query = 'SELECT * FROM teams WHERE league ='.trim($number);
```

Answer (score 3):

Enclose it in quotes.

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM teams WHERE league = '{$number}'";
```

Non numeric values not in quotes are interpretted by MySQL as entity names.  In the context it's in, MySQL would expect that entity name to be that of a column.

Comment: No problem.  By the way, I'm assuming your strings are literally coming from the array.  If they're not (which I have to wonder about since trim is useless if they are), then you should probably pass number through mysql_real_escape_string.